# Using glyphicon-facebook from bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to use `glyphicon-facebook`. `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">` works but why doesn't `<i class="glyphicon-facebook">` work? And also there is no option such as `'glyphicon glyphicon-facebook'`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no glyphicon-facebook glyph in the Bootstrap glyph library:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Take a look at [fontastic.me](http://fontastic.me/).  You can create custom sets of glyphs and there are a tonne of free glyphs to choose from including facebook glphys.

Another alternative is [icomoon.io](http://icomoon.io/)

Answer (score 14):

You can also try http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/
This is a very nice set of icons, pretty much everything you'll ever need.

Answer (score 4):

add in header file and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

use `<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>`

for different logo you have to use different name here is the list of icons and their code http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Answer (score -2):

This fontawesome class offers a facebook icon:

https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_brand.asp

```
<ul class="face">
    <a class="fa fa-facebook-official" id="face_0" href="">
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer, it is unclear

Comment: Sorry about that I thought that the link I had left, provided all the information needed.